# syntax error 'expecting a (' even though code runs correctly

Tags: sas, column-width

When running the following code

```
proc print data=cmissing label style(column)={width=min};
run;
```

I get this error

```
 259        proc print data=cmissing label style(column)={width=min};
                                                                   _
                                                                   79
                                                                   76
 ERROR 79-322: Expecting a (.
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

I don't understand what this error means or how to fix it. Even though it claims the statement is ignored, the width argument does work (when changing min to 5cm for example).

Any tips are more than welcome! Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The WIDTH style option is not supported by PROC PRINT.  Did you just want to use the normal PROC PRINT option of `width=min` instead of trying to modify the column (aka data) style?  Is there some other style option you want to change?

Comment: Yes, width=min works perfectly. Thank you very much, Tom! I don't want to change any other style option; was just unsure about the syntax.